# Not able to load the 'forecast' or 'auto.arima' functions

Tags: r

Although I installed the required packages to execute auto.arima(),  im not able to do so. Can anybody navigate through this problem[image: see the screen shot]

And further i tried to install "Rccp", but that also failed. Need the solution asap, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing the needs package which takes care of all your dependencies.

`install.packages('needs')
 needs(forecast)
 ?forecast`

Comment: thanks.. bt actually i was using **3.3.1** (not a stable release of R) so i revert back to  **3.3.0** it got resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

you must install the package with dependencies:

**install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)**